# imsharpen in older matlab releases

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I need to use the MATLAB function [`imsharpen`](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/images/ref/imsharpen.html#btppxju-3_1)
which was introduced in R2013a.

Is there an unofficial version of this function that works for an older release of MATLAB?

Comment: Probably not. Else, try to find the fileexchange.

Comment: read this comment by Steve Eddins: http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2013/06/05/r2013a-image-processing-and-computer-vision/#comment-26560